# Is there a way to disable extensions and make them available to the user only when they have purchased it on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app with multiple extensions on iOS. I want to make the extensions available only to premium users while users who do not intend to purchase the extensions can still use the app to its full functionality. Is there a way to lock and unlock app extensions on iOS?

Comment: As in like today extensions? Like the ones you see when you swipe down from the top of the screen?

Comment: Yes, I mean any extensions, including Today extensions and custom keyboard extensions.